# How do I start a CompletableFuture without blocking and do something when it's done?

Tags: java, completable-future

The `CompletableFuture` API is fairly intimidating, lot's of accepts, and thens and other things; it's hard to tell why different options exist.

```
CompletableFuture<?> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->..., executor)

future.startNonBlocking...( (...) -> { callback behavior done when complete }
```

I'm basically trying to mimic a `new Thread(() -> dostuff).start()` but with better thread pooling, error handling, etc. Note: I don't actually need the `Runnable` interface here, I'm generifying a piece of existing code.

what's the right way to start my asynchronous task and execute behavior when it's complete? or handle an exception that is thrown?

Comment: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple async callback:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> [result]).thenAccept(result -> [action]);
```

Or if you need error handling:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> [result]).whenComplete((result, exception) -> {
    if (exception != null) {
        // handle exception
    } else {
        // handle result
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new Thread(() -> dostuff).start()
```

means that *dostuff* implements *Runnable*, so you may use

```
static CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable runnable)    
static CompletableFuture<Void> runAsync(Runnable runnable, Executor executor)
```

also.